# Remove objects in the canvas in certain coordinates

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the balls already generated in the canvas on the click and decrease the counter on the bottom, but my function does not work. Here is my code concerning the part of the ball removal.
Is it possible to use a div to get the same result and to facilitate the removal of the balls? thank you

```
    ball.onclick = function removeBalls(event) {


    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;

    ctx.clearRect(x, y, 100, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Balls Counter: " + balls.length - 1, 10, canvas.height - 10);

}
```

below I enclose my complete code

```js
// GLOBAL VARIBLES

var gravity = 4;
var forceFactor = 0.3; //0.3 0.5
var mouseDown = false;
var balls = []; //hold all the balls
var mousePos = []; //hold the positions of the mouse
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var heightBrw = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var widthBrw = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var bounciness = 1; //0.9

window.onload = function gameCore() {

    function onMouseDown(event) {
        mouseDown = true;
        mousePos["downX"] = event.pageX;
        mousePos["downY"] = event.pageY;
    }

    canvas.onclick = function onMouseUp(event) {

        mouseDown = false;
        balls.push(new ball(mousePos["downX"], mousePos["downY"], (event.pageX - mousePos["downX"]) * forceFactor,
            (event.pageY - mousePos["downY"]) * forceFactor, 5 + (Math.random() * 10), bounciness, random_color()));
        ball
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        mousePos['currentX'] = event.pageX;
        mousePos['currentY'] = event.pageY;
    }
    function resizeWindow(event) {
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    }

    function reduceBounciness(event) {

        if (bounciness == 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {


                balls[i].b = bounciness = 0.9;
                document.getElementById("btn-bounciness").value = "⤽ Bounciness";

            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                balls[i].b = bounciness = 1;
                document.getElementById("btn-bounciness").value = " ⤼ Bounciness";
            }
        }

        return bounciness;
    }

    function reduceSpeed(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
            balls[i].vx = velocityX = 20 + c;
            balls[i].vy = velocityY = 20 + c;
        }
    }

    function speedUp(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
            balls[i].vx = velocityX = 120 + c;
            balls[i].vy = velocityY = 120 + c;
        }
    }

    function stopGravity(event) {
        if (gravity == 4) {
            for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                balls[i].g = gravity = 0;
                balls[i].vx = velocityX = 0;
                balls[i].vy = velocityY = 0;
                document.getElementById("btn-gravity").value = "►";
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                balls[i].g = gravity = 4;
                balls[i].vx = velocityX = 100;
                balls[i].vy = velocityY = 100;
                document.getElementById("btn-gravity").value = "◾";
            }
        }


    }


    ball.onclick = function removeBalls(event) {


        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;

        ctx.clearRect(x, y, 100, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("Balls Counter: " + balls.length - 1, 10, canvas.height - 10);

    }


    document.getElementById("btn-gravity").addEventListener("click", stopGravity);
    document.getElementById("btn-speed-up").addEventListener("click", speedUp);
    document.getElementById("btn-speed-down").addEventListener("click", reduceSpeed);
    document.getElementById("btn-bounciness").addEventListener("click", reduceBounciness);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow);

}

// GRAPHICS CODE
function circle(x, y, r, c) { // x position, y position, r radius, c color 
    //draw a circle
    ctx.beginPath(); //approfondire
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    //fill
    ctx.fillStyle = c;
    ctx.fill();
    //stroke
    ctx.lineWidth = r * 0.1; //border of the ball radius * 0.1
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000"; //color of the border 
    ctx.stroke();
}
function random_color() {
    var letter = "0123456789ABCDEF".split(""); //exadecimal value for the colors
    var color = "#"; //all the exadecimal colors starts with #
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color = color + letter[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
function selectDirection(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
    ctx.moveTo(tox, toy);

}

//per velocità invariata rimuovere bounciness
function draw_ball() {
    this.vy = this.vy + gravity * 0.1; // v = a * t
    this.x = this.x + this.vx * 0.1; // s = v * t
    this.y = this.y + this.vy * 0.1;

    if (this.x + this.r > canvas.width) {
        this.x = canvas.width - this.r;
        this.vx = this.vx * -1 * this.b;
    }
    if (this.x - this.r < 0) {
        this.x = this.r;
        this.vx = this.vx * -1 * this.b;
    }
    if (this.y + this.r > canvas.height) {
        this.y = canvas.height - this.r;
        this.vy = this.vy * -1 * this.b;
    }
    if (this.y - this.r < 0) {
        this.y = this.r;
        this.vy = this.vy * 1 * this.b;
    }

    circle(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.c);
}
// OBJECTS
function ball(positionX, positionY, velosityX, velosityY, radius, bounciness, color, gravity) {
    this.x = positionX;
    this.y = positionY;
    this.vx = velosityX;
    this.vy = velosityY;
    this.r = radius;
    this.b = bounciness;
    this.c = color;
    this.g = gravity;
    this.draw = draw_ball;

}

// GAME LOOP
function game_loop() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (mouseDown == true) {
        selectDirection(mousePos['downX'], mousePos['downY'], mousePos['currentX'], mousePos['currentY']);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {

        balls[i].draw();
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Balls Counter: " + balls.length, 10, canvas.height - 10);
}

setInterval(game_loop, 10);
```

```css
* { 
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
 }
html, body { 
    width: 100%; height: 100%;

 }
#canvas { 
    display: block;
    height: 95%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;
   
 }


#btn-speed-up, #btn-speed-down, #btn-bounciness, #btn-gravity{
    padding: 0.4%;
    background-color: beige;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top:0.5%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Power Balls</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
   
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  
    <input type="button" value="⤼ Bounciness" id="btn-bounciness"></input> 
    <input type="button" onclick="c+=10" value="+ Speed" id="btn-speed-up"></input> 

    <input type="button" value="◾" id="btn-gravity"></input> 
    <input type="button" onclick="c+= -10" value=" - Speed" id="btn-speed-down"></input> 
   
    
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: onmousedown and onclick is will get conflicted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

- `ball.onclick` will not get triggered, as `ball` it is not a DOM object. Instead, you need to work with `canvas.onclick`. Check whether the user clicked on a ball or on empty space to decide whether to delete or create a ball.
- To delete the ball, `ctx.clearRect` is not sufficient. This will clear the ball from the currently drawn frame, but the object still remains in the array `balls` and will therefore be drawn again in the next frame via `balls[i].draw();`. Instead, you need to remove the clicked ball entirely from the array, e. g. [by using `splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

---

Otherwise, nice demo! :)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done because the canvas is an immediate mode API. All you can do is draw over the top but this is not reliable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)

You will have to store each item in a separate data structure, then re-draw whenever a change occurs. In your case there is an array of balls, so you should remove the one that was clicked, before redrawing the entire array.

Each time you remove something, clear the canvas then re-draw each ball.

There are optimisations you can make if this is too slow.